# Unit Test not Returning Expected Value

Tags: apex, unit-test, dml

In an Apex class, I've got a simple `Boolean` that sets itself to either `true` or `false` depending on whether the field (Picklist) `Candidate_Type__c` is equal to:

- Contract/Interim
- Permanent

See below:

```
public Boolean isContractInterim {
  get {
    if (isContractInterim == null) {
      String candidateType = [SELECT Candidate_Type__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :con.Id].Candidate_Type__c;

      if (candidateType == 'Contract/Interim') {
        isContractInterim = true;
      }
      else {
        isContractInterim = false;
      }
    }

    return isContractInterim;
  }
  set;
}
```

To quickly write a unit test for this, in the `@testSetup` annotated method I used the following:

```
Contact con = new Contact(
  FirstName = 'Joe',
  LastName = 'Allen',
  Candidate_Type__c = 'Contract/Interim'
);

INSERT con;
```

And ran this unit test:

```
@isTest static void test_is_contract_interim() {
  Contact con = [SELECT Id, Candidate_Type__c FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Joe Allen'];

  System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@ ' + con);

  LatestCandidatePrescreenCont controller = new LatestCandidatePrescreenCont(new ApexPages.StandardController(con));

  System.assertEquals(true, controller.isContractInterim);
}
```

What's strange here is that `con` only seemed to debug the `Id` and not `Candidate_Type__c` (as though it's somehow not being set?) and the assertion failed citing it was `false` when I was expecting `true`.

I've managed to get around this by removing the `Candidate_Type__c = 'Contract/Interim'` line from `@testSetup` and instead performing an `UPDATE` DML inside the method which ultimately passes it:

```
@isTest static void test_is_contract_interim() {
  Contact con = [SELECT Id, Candidate_Type__c FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Joe Allen'];
  con.Candidate_Type__c = 'Contract/Interim';

  UPDATE con;

  System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@ ' + con);

  LatestCandidatePrescreenCont controller = new LatestCandidatePrescreenCont(new ApexPages.StandardController(con));

  System.assertEquals(true, controller.isContractInterim);
}
```

I'm stumped here though as to why I have to update it to get it to return what I expect?

Comment: Have you tried querying con back again after your DML update? If there's a trigger or workflow clearing the picklist, then querying it back would help you to discover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a similar test here and everything worked fine, creating a Contact in a @testSetup annotated method, using a picklist, testing a static boolean in a controller, etc. So I guess there is nothing wrong about this structure.

As you noticed in your code, the debug is not printing the Candidate_Type__c you just set, so I guess there is some other thing such as as workflow rule or trigger updating your Contact as soon as you create it and affecting your results.

Comment: To be honest I didn't even consider Workflow Rules or Triggers. It's been a long day! Thanks for jogging my memory.